# How test controls in WinRT

Tags: c#, testing, windows-runtime

I have a Metro app and I created a few controls. I want to test them, but looks like test envoirement do not emulate UI flow.

I want to write following test:

```
[UITestMethod]
public void Template_ShouldBeDefined()
{
    var c = new LoginControl();
    // Attach object to UI tree
    Window.Current.Content = c;

    Assert.IsNotNull(c.Template);
    Assert.AreEqual(typeof(LoginControl), c.Template.TargetType);
}
```

This test will pass in silverlight and wpf, but here not.

It is possible, to making it work?

Comment: Might it be that the control is not immediately rendered by WinRT and thus the template is not set yet? (Sorry for re-opening this question but I'm currently dealing with the same problem).

Comment: I tried to write test with some delay, but effect is the same. I think that UI is not initialized in that tests and UITestMethod causes only that test is running on UIThread. 

Maybe after year something changed. I think that if Coded UI Tests will be available for windows store apps then similiar tests should be available to write.

EDIT: I found this article about CodedUITest in WinRt, but I didn't test it: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2013/06/27/using-coded-ui-to-test-xaml-based-windows-store-apps.aspx